# Whats wrong with my .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Designed to bring up a specific error .php page when someone doesnt enter right credentials, but seems to bring up its own. Also protects all my directories regardless of which one it is placed in.
Has 777 permission.

```
ErrorDocument 401 Mywebsite.com/CustomError.php

AuthName "My Password Protected Site" AuthUserFile
MYwebsite.com/Folder/.htpasswd 
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

# Set REMOTE_USER env variable on 401 ErrorDocument
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^401$
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{ENV:REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER}]
```

Here's what it always says as of now:

Authorization Required

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

I used to have the spefic directories as /folder/file instead of website/folder/file but when i did that, the error page would have this line as well:

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: ok, first thing, always flush your browser cache when you play with htaccess... or add random parameters in your url

Comment: /me thinks the `AuthUserFile` should be on the start of the next line, not at the end there?

Comment: Ill try rearranging the file...what sort of random parameters do you mean?

Comment: Move `AuthUserFile` to newline and make sure its value is an absolute path e.g. ``/MYwebsite.com/Folder/.htpasswd`` not ``MYwebsite.com/Folder/.htpasswd``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
ErrorDocument 401 Mywebsite.com/CustomError.php
```

According to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve. Alternatively, a message can be provided to be displayed by the browser. Examples:
>
> `ErrorDocument 500 http://foo.example.com/cgi-bin/tester`
> `ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/bad_urls.pl`
> `ErrorDocument 401 /subscription_info.html`
> `ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry can't allow you access today"`
>
> Additionally, the special value default can be used to specify Apache's simple hardcoded message. While not required under normal circumstances, default will restore Apache's simple hardcoded message for configurations that would otherwise inherit an existing ErrorDocument.
>
> `ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/bad_urls.pl`
>
> `<Directory /web/docs>`
> `ErrorDocument 404 default`
> `</Directory>`

So you can't have `Mywebsite.com/CustomError.php` as the second parameter, it's got to be a full URL starting with `http://`, an absolute path that starts with a `/`, or a message. You can't have relative paths as the second parameter.